# How can I put an Android app that I'm developing onto a phone?

Tags: android

As the title say I am making an android app and need to test it on the phone... I have run it in the emulator but now I want to actually put it onto the android phone.. problem is i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Some phones require software/drivers from the manufacturer. Don't forget to download those if necessary.

Comment: could you specify the question. I is this about running from the dev env ( what the answers are headed) or is it about actually putting the app as an app on the phone without the need of a usb connection to the computer. also, edit the title accordingly please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use USB-Debugging-Mode. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Answer (score 1):

> Turn on "USB Debugging" on your device. On the device, go to Settings
>   Applications > Development and enable USB debugging.

Plug your phone to the Computer and assuming your using eclipse run the app if the run configuration is set to manual you can now choose your device and run but if it setup to run on the emulator you have to go to run configuration > target > manual.

Answer (score 0):

plug your phone into your computer after enabling USB-debugging (settings>applications>manage applications> development) and then run the application like your phone was an emulator, this should install the app on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

dude infact you can just copy paste the apk file from your PC into the sd card and then install directly onto phone.
or just transfer that apk from PC via bluetooth to phone. and install just by clicking that received apk file..